# How to execute batch file on the same executable as the "main" C# application

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have a given C# executable and I want to execute a batch file inside this executable. The batch file sets environment variables, and some of these operations are conditional to other environment variables (IF conditions).

I want these environment variables to be set inside the executable itself, so that the environment variables are set on the current executable.

Absolutely every method that I can find on our friend google when I write something like “C# execute batch same process” seem to be based on the method `System.Diagnostics.Process` method, which executes the batch file on a different process.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "execute a batch file inside this executable" exactly? The command line will handle your batch file (which is obviously a different process). Are you trying to have C# code that can interpret a batch file and act on the commands directly? If so, my next question would be "why?" Could you explain your use case? I can't really think of a good reason why `System.Diagnostics.Process` wouldn't be sufficient in most cases.

Comment: Well, afaik there is no internal batch-executor in the dotnet framework (nor core), so that's what you're down to. What you _could_ do is to embed a script engine into your executable, but if you want (or have to) stick with batch, then there's Process...

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Explain your scenario better. You mean that after you `Porcess.Start()` a batch file which does some `set X=Y` calls, you want your .NET executable to return those variables when you call `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("X")`?

Comment: You could execute your executable from within the batch file, which would let the executable use the same environment as used (and set/modified by) the batch file (with regard to environment variables).

Comment: The scenario is simple: I have a console application. I want this console application to interpret the commands inside that batch file so that the environment variables set within that batch file are taken into account on the console application.

Comment: Why do you need to use a batch file to do that? You can set environment variables in C# directly.

Comment: Apps are passed a *copy* of the enviro settings precisely so another process cannot make the kinds of changes you are proposing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a console application. I want this console application to interpret the commands inside that batch file so that the environment variables set within that batch file are taken into account on the console application.

But you definitely don't want to write a batch script interpreter in C#.

If you want your console app to use the environment variables assigned in the batch script, then start your executable at the end of that batch script.

Your application will then inherit that environment, and therefore those environment variables.

If you can't alter said batch script, then create a new batch script that:

- Runs the original batch script, then
- Runs your executable.

Comment: The code I am working on is meant to launch an older application which is currently launched via multiple batch calls. I am perfectly aware that the “ideal” would be setting all the environment variables before my executable, or set all these environment variables through C#, but I cannot do this because the decrepit system in which I need to implement this is based on bach files.

The scenario is: I have application A already running, and I want the environment variables which are defined on batch file “B.bat” to be set on application A. My only question is if there is a way to do so?